# #aureliajs custom element via inheritance

Tags: aurelia

I've built 2 custom elements deriving them from a base class and using @useView decorator. But it looks like it does not work to use both of them in the same view, only first one will appear.
Illustrated here
https://gist.run/?id=897298ab1dad92fadca77f64653cf32c

What did I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using inheritence is not recommended when building Aurelia applications. We recommended using composition via the Dependency Injection container rather than inheritence. This is because, in general, Dependency Injection and Inheritance don't mix very well. This isn't an Aurelia thing, this is just part of how dependency injection (specifically constructor injection) work.

I would recommend changing how you are doing this to stop using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Ashley beat me to it! Just for the record, here are the code changes in your gist:

base.html

```
<template style="display: block;">
  It sure did
  <input type="text" value.two-way="base.search">
  <span>${base.search}</span>
</template>
```

base.js

```
import {transient} from 'aurelia-framework';
@transient()
export class Base {
  search = "base";

  log() {
    console.log(`${this.search}`);
  }
}
```

derived.js

```
import {useView, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Base} from './base'
@useView('base.html')
@inject(Base)
export class Derived
{
  constructor(base) {
    this.base = base;
  }

  bind()
  {
    this.base.search="derived";
  }
}
```

derived2.js

```
import {useView, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Base} from './base';
@useView('base.html')
@inject(Base)
export class Derived2 {
  constructor(base) {
    this.base = base;
  }

   bind()
  {
    this.base.search="derived2";
  }
}
```

Comment: How it would work together with shared @bindable property?

Comment: @Lumdeia Good question. Ashley